# Why dose go store value of pointer semantics on the heap?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

William Kennedy(author of go in action) said that In go, there are two semantics. Value semantics, which stored on stack, mean that we’re making a copy of the value as we go across these program boundaries. Pointer semantics, which stored on heap, mean that we’re sharing the value as we go across there program boundaries. Garbage collector will kick in sometimes to recycle the unused memory on heap. I want to know why the values of pointer semantics are stored on heap. Could you explain?

Comment: This is not an accurate description of how Go chooses where to store things.

Comment: All pointers point to the heap because pointers to the stack are not useful very long. The stack changes every time a function is entered and exited. Pointer values are not necessarily stored on the heap though, and there is no guarantee that all non-pointer values are allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime a value is shared outside the scope of a function’s stack frame, it will be placed (or allocated) on the heap. It’s the job of the escape analysis algorithms to find these situations and maintain a level of integrity in the program. The integrity is in making sure that access to any value is always accurate, consistent and efficient.

Reference: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/05/language-mechanics-on-escape-analysis.html